# Cant extract value using select and find methods in bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract some information from a tag in the following code example using bs4 python

```
<div class"name">
   <h1 class="fullname"> John Martin </h1>
```

What i have tried is these two methods using `soup.find` and `soup.select`

1)

```
name= soup.find('h1', class_='name').get_text()
        print(name)
```

2)

```
n=soup.select(".fullname h1").get_text()
    print(n)
```

Both give errors

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
and other is []
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You probably meant `class_='fullname'`. There is no `h1` with a `class='name'`. Voting to close as a typo/no longer reproducible/resolved in a way that won't be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the class attribute should be `fullname`

In the second example, the CSS selector should be `h1.fullname` -> select `<h1>` with `class=fullname`. Also, change the method to `select_one()` to select only one element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class"name">
   <h1 class="fullname"> John Martin </h1>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

name= soup.find('h1', class_='fullname').get_text() # <-- change to fullname
print(name)

n=soup.select_one("h1.fullname").get_text() # <-- change to h1.fullname and .select_one()
print(n)
```

Prints:

```
 John Martin 
 John Martin
```

---

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' (First example)

Comment: @user3415869 Are you running the _exact_ example as stated in my answer? Because it's working here. If you're using Jupyter notebook - reset/reload it.

Comment: @user3415869 What version of `bs4` are you using? I'm using version `4.8.1`. Also, use the **exact** code that I've in the answer (with `html.parser`). The result must be exactly the same -> two times "John Martin".

Comment: so the full name is replaced by title title--size1 bio-info__name. Are they three classes?

Comment: error:     n=soup.select_one('.title.title--size1.bio-info__name').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: n=soup.select_one("h1.title.title--size1.bio-info__name").get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: @user3415869 Use **exact** code that I have in my answer. I think you are using your `soup` variable from somewhere else. These tags you see in Firefox/Chrome might be injected by Javascript. Use `print(soup)` to print your soup to the screen and see if the tags/classes are _really_ there.

Comment: you were right. it was declared somewhere else.can i do it with the soup.find?

Comment: @user3415869 You can use `.find()` to find one element, or `.find_all()` to find a list of elements (or `None`). It depends on your use case.